# Sudden segmentation fault when accessing array after malloc()

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I have an Array `char *Input[11]`. I use `malloc()` to allocate memory to it.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) 
        Input[i] = "\0";

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {

        Input[i] = malloc( 256 * sizeof(char) );
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        strcpy(Input[i], "test");
    }

    printf("Input[11] is %s\n", Input[11]); // <- Here the seg fault happens
```

When I want to acess `Input[11]`afterwards I get a segmentation fault. I read that you usually get this error in the context when there is nothing where `Input[11]`points to so I guess there is something wrong with how I allocate memory. Accessing `Input[10]`and below works fine. I checked it with valgrind and that is the error message:

```
==5633== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==5633== Invalid read of size 1
==5633==    at 0x4098383: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==5633==    by 0x409D695: printf (printf.c:33)
==5633==    by 0x8048A15: handle_command (swebsh.c:122)
==5633==    by 0x8048BE6: main (swebsh.c:181)
==5633==  Address 0x6e69622f is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

However, I'm not really sure what this tells me except of where the error is. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Oops, forget the initialisation when simplifying the code!

Comment: Unsimplify it some more. How is `Input` defined? Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to begin with, instead of editing the code in ways that invalidate peoples answers.

Comment: And read this https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I was going to post a comment to the answer, but it got deleted. Will try a second edit and see if that helps.

Comment: Of course I deleted it. It doesn't answer the question. Which is why I emphasize: write your question with the proper example to begin with. Nobody is holding a stop watch and timing you on how fast you can post a question.

Comment: Please post an [mcve]. The problem is probably in code you have not shown.

Comment: And concering your link - "I wrote this program for my assignment and it doesn’t work." What the? I was trying to debug and google for hours now and I used the stack overflow search function. Isn't this a side to ask for help when needed?

Comment: @Yíu, this is a site with a specific Q&A format (about which you can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)). Eric Lipperts post exemplify a particular brand of question which are often asked here, but don't really belong. You don't have a question. You have a problem that you want someone to figure out for you. Eric accurately points out, that you most likely haven't exhausted all options before asking.

Comment: @StoryTeller "You don't have a question. You have a problem that you want someone to figure out for you." There is a question, which asks "What in this code can produce this error?" I know it's not a great question, but I can learn something from asking more experienced people for help after investing a lot of effort myself without success. But if you feel like jumping to conclusions and kind of putting me as lazy without own effort then maybe you are the one with the ignorant perspective here.

Comment: I assure you I have some experience regarding the quality of questions on SO.  I wasn't wrong when I suggested you asked without exhausting all options first. Now, you can get up in arms about hearing this criticism, and continue to rely on others to debug your code for you, or you can read the post by Eric, and be able to help yourself immensely in your own future. Suit yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an array has N elements then the valid range of indices is `[0, N-1]` In your code snippet you declared an array as having 11 elements. Thus the valid range of indices for your array is `[0, 10]`.

To avoid such kind of errors as you did do not use magic numbers. Instead use some names for them.

Your code can be rewritten the following way

```
#define N 11

//...

char *Input[N] = { 0 };
int length = 256;

for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    Input[i] = malloc( length * sizeof( char ) );
}

for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) strcpy( Input[i], "test" );

printf( "Input[N - 1] is %s\n", Input[N - 1] );
```